# hadoop streaming Failed on local exception: java.net.SocketException: Host is down;

Tags: hadoop, socketexception

I have a 1 node cluster running on my mac and can create a dir in hdfs and put a file

```
hadoop fs -mkdir sampleData
hadoop fs -put ~/SampleTweets.csv sampleData
```

but when i run a simple streaming job as below get an error (shown below code)

```
hadoop jar    
~/cloudera/cdh5.5/hadoop/share/hadoop/mapreduce1/contrib/streaming/hadoop-
streaming-2.6.0-mr1-cdh5.5.1.jar \
-Dmapred.reduce.tasks=1 \
-input sampleData \
-output sampleData/output1 \
-mapper cat \
-reducer "wc -l"
```

Error on screen and http://localhost:8088/cluster/app/application_1453348020587_0005

```
Application application_1453348020587_0005 failed 2 times due to Error launching appattempt_1453348020587_0005_000002. 
Got exception: java.io.IOException: Failed on local exception: java.net.SocketException: 
Host is down; Host Details : local host is: "tanna-iMac.local/192.168.1.13"; 
destination host is: "192.168.1.4":58893;
```

My /etc/hosts:

```
cat /etc/hosts
  127.0.0.1 localhost
  255.255.255.255   broadcasthost
  192.168.1.13 localhost
  ::1 localhost
  fe80::1%lo0   localhost
```

Not sure where its picking up destination host 192.168.1.4 from? and what service is running on port 58893

Comment: Are you using Ambari for management? If so, check to see what alerts you have. I frequently got that error when I was streaming to HBase and I discovered my HBase Master was giving me problems